# Python, involving defining a class

Tags: python, class, methods

I have this problem I am trying to solve:

Write the definition of a class  ContestResult containing:

•An instance variable   winner of type  String , initialized to the empty String.

•An instance variable   second_place of type  String , initialized to the empty String.

•An instance variable   third_place of type  String , initialized to the empty String.

•A method called  set_winner that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance variable   winner .

•A method called  set_second_place that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance variable   second_place .

•A method called  set_third_place that has one parameter, whose value it assigns to the instance variable   third_place .

•A method called  get_winner that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance variable   winner .

•A method called  get_second_place that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance variable   second_place .

•A method called  get_third_place that has no parameters and that returns the value of the instance variable   third_place .

This is my code:

```
class ContestResult():
    def __init__(self):
        self.winner= ""
        self.second_place= ""
        self.third_place= ""
    def set_winner(self,value):
        self.winner= value.set_winner
    def set_second_place(self,value):
        self.second_place= value_set_second_place
    def set_third_place(self,value):
        self.third_place= value.set_third_place
    def get_winner(self):
        return self.winner
    def get_second_place(self):
        return self.second_place
    def get_third_place(self):
        return self.third_place
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Exception occurred(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'set_winner'",)
```

Can someone help me with this? Please and thank you.

Comment: The error says *a String* does not have `set_winner`.

Comment: @user2864740 except that it perfectly describes the problem? "Hey, something's wrong in here because you're trying to call `str.set_winner` and that don't exist." It's true that it's a class method, and not the class itself, that's wrong, but that seems a fine hair to split.

Comment: @AdamSmith I was providing a friendly translation of the message. The error comes because `set_winner` was applied upon *a String* (aka 'str'). This information can be used to track back the problem - mainly, *where* is `set_winner` used and *why* was it applied to a string?

Comment: `value.set_winner` what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 3):

One are passing in a string to `set_winner`. That is why you're seeing the error.

However, you don't need to create the `set_winner` and `get_winner` functions in Python. All of the object's member variables, in this case winner, second_place and third_place, are publicly accessible. If you really want to have mutators and accessors, the Pythonic way of doing so is with `property`:

```
 class ContestResult(object):
   def __init__(self):
     self.__winner = ''

   @property
   def winner(self):
     return self.__winner

   @winner.setter
   def winner(self, value):
     print "I'm about to set the value of winner"
     self.__winner = value
```

and now when you want to see the "winner" property:

```
   foo = ContestResult()
   foo.winner = "Frank"
```

it works just like a regular member variable.

Answer (score 2):

in `def set_winner(self,value)`, presumably `value` is a string, right? Why are you calling `value.set_winner`?

```
self.winner = value
```

Note that this is true for all your `set_`s.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't catch that myself.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all that with Python unless you're trying to modify the way attributes are actually get and set.

```
class ContestResult(object):
    def __init__(self, winner, second_place, third_place):
        self.winner = winner
        self.second_place = second_place
        self.third_place = third_place

Stick = ContestResult("Foo", "Bar", "Eggs")
Stick.second_place #gets "Bar"
Stick.winner = "Clown" #sets Stick.winner
```

Python isn't Java :) you don't need those methods -- again, unless you're going to be modifying the data or decorate the method or something. In which case you can use the `@property` syntax as outlined by wheaties -- and in doing so, you *still* don't actually call the `get` or `set` methods, you just interact in a Pythonic way and use assignment.

```
Stick.second_place = "Earl" #this will call the property setter
```